# Having trouble with joining tables in query

Tags: mysql, sql

**DB Table Structure:**

Session Table (aka Exam Table)

```
SessionId(auto)  SessionName
137              XULWQ
```

Question Table:

```
SessionId  QuestionId QuestionContent  QuestionNo QuestionMarks  OptionId
137        1          Name 2 Things     1         5               5
137        2          Name 3 Things     2         5               2
```

Option_Table Table:

```
OptionId  OptionType
1         A-C
2         A-D
3         A-E
4         A-F
5         A-G
6         A-H
```

Answer Table:

```
 AnswerId(auto) SessionId  QuestionId  Answer
   200            137        1           B
   201            137        1           F
   202            137        2           D
   203            137        2           A
   204            137        2           C
```

I am having trouble compiling the query below. I want to select the following fields undeneath in the query but the problem I am having is with my joins. If you look at the last join I am trying to retrieve `OptionID` from `Option_Table` Table but I have to go through the `Answer` table which doesn't have that field. My problem is that I have 3 fields which actually rely on joining with the Question` Table.

My question is what is the correct way of joining the tables below so that it displays the answers for each question with the fields I want to SELECT?

```
SELECT q.SessionId, s.SessionName, q.QuestionId, q.QuestionNo, q.QuestionContent, an.Answer, an.AnswerId, q.QuestionMarks, q.OptionId, o.OptionType
       FROM Session s 
       INNER JOIN Question q ON s.SessionId = q.SessionId
       JOIN Answer an ON q.QuestionId = an.QuestionId
       JOIN Option_Table o ON an.OptionId = o.OptionId
       WHERE s.SessionName = ?
       ORDER BY q.QuestionId, an.Answer
```

Output required:

[image]

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: I included the output wanted from query in a screen shot. Im sorry it might be difficult to see

Comment: @user1881090 ok, but, did you tried some of the answers?

Comment: @Lamak Just put a comment under your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Question q 
    INNER JOIN Answer a ON q.QuestionID = a.QuestionID
    INNER JOIN Option_Table ot ON ot.optionID = q.optionID
    INNER JOIN session s ON s.sessionid = q.sessionid
```

Answer (score 4):

Just change that `JOIN` condition to use the column from the table `Question`:

```
SELECT  q.SessionId, s.SessionName, q.QuestionId, q.QuestionNo, 
        q.QuestionContent, an.Answer, an.AnswerId, q.QuestionMarks, 
        q.OptionId, o.OptionType
FROM `Session` s 
INNER JOIN `Question` q 
    ON s.SessionId = q.SessionId
INNER JOIN `Answer` an 
    ON q.QuestionId = an.QuestionId
INNER JOIN `Option` o 
    ON q.OptionId = o.OptionId
WHERE s.SessionName = ?
ORDER BY q.QuestionId, an.Answer
```

Comment: I have tried this but I get a syntax error referring from your last inner join to the order by clause. Can I still refer to q.QuestionId when the join is the `Answer` Table?

Comment: @user1881090 an error from my last inner join to the order by clause?, I don't think I get what you mean. Can you post the error message?. Just because the `JOIN` is after the join with table `Answer`, it doesn't means that the join is against that table

Comment: @Lamak you might want backticks around `option` it is a reserved word.

Comment: @bluefeet I thought about it too, but I had the impression that op was actually running his query

Comment: I got the correct answer brkyneval. I didn't realize that you called it `Option` Table, it is `Option_Table`.

Comment: upvote for answer. I already accepted somebody else's answer as that one out of three i tested was working first

Comment: @user1881090 ok, then you should change the query you posted since its using that table (it's not that I called it like that). And its perfectly fine that you accepted that answer

Comment: That is strange, can't remember changing it from Option_Table to Option in query but my bad, sorry bout that

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    s.SessionId ,
    s.SessionName,
    q.QuestionId,
    q.QuestionNo,
    q.QuestionContent,
    a.Answer,
    a.AnswerId,
    q.QuestionMarks,
    ot.OptionId,
    ot.OptionType  
FROM    Session as s
LEFT JOIN Question as q ON s.SessionId = q.SessionId
LEFT JOIN Option_Table as ot ON ot.OptionId = q.OptionId 
LEFT JOIN Answer as a ON a.QuestionId = q.QuestionId
```

Comment: There is no SessionId in Option_Table

Comment: @user1881090 take a look this might solve your issue i have edited

Comment: upvote for answer. I already accepted somebody else's answer as that one out of three i tested was working first